# java ООП вызов метода из других классов

Tags: java, ооп

Программирование начал изучать не так давно и у меня возник такой вопрос каким способом лучше вызывать метод из других классов. например у меня есть такой класс и метод код в котором всегда один и тот же(неизменяем):

```
public class Utils {

 int calculation(int value) {

        int result = 5 + value
        return result;
    }
}
```

вызвать из других классов я могу разными способами например создать объект класса Utils и вызвать метод

```
public class A {

 Utils utils = new Utils();
 utils.calculation(10);

}
```

```
public class B {

 Utils utils = new Utils();
 utils.calculation(15);

}
```

но если в классе Utils много методов и каждый раз создавать новый объект в разных классах то как мне кажется это лишний расход памяти.
Можно сделать метод static но как я понял программисты не очень любят статичные поля и методы из за того что трудно за ними следить и можно получить утечку памяти и т.д.
Так же есть шаблон singleton с помощью которого создаётся объект только один раз.
Как правильно это сделать в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *программисты не очень любят статичные поля и методы из за того что трудно за ними следить и можно получить утечку памяти*

С правильно реализованными статическими методами равно как и с неизменяемыми статическими полями таких проблем не возникает по определению.

Судя по вашему описанию, у вас используются *чистые функции*, не связанные с бизнес-логикой -- т.е. такие, которые обрабатывают только входные аргументы без побочных эффектов и изменения некоего состояния *за пределами* данной функции, возвращая всегда один и тот же ответ для заданных входных параметров,-- их как раз рекомендуется выносить в так называемые утилитарные классы в качестве статических методов.

В частности, это позволяет избежать дублирования кода и значительно упростить тестирование таких функций.  Также такие функции являются потокобезопасными.

Примером такой реализации являются хорошо известный класс `Math`, реализующий вычисления множества математических функций, или статические фабричные методы интерфейса `Comparator`, позволяющие создать нужный компаратор для объектов заданного типа.

Оговорка о бизнес-логике связана с тем, что бизнес-логика подвержена изменениям, и потому должна быть легко заменяема, например, при помощи классов-потомков.  Таким образом, статические методы не применимы для таких целей.

Для утилитарных классов характерно наличие приватного дефолтного конструктора, который может быть пустым, или даже выбрасывать исключение типа `UnsupportedOperationException` (см. [Lombok `@UtilityClass`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass))

---

Связанный вопрос: [Утилитарные классы - добро или зло?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/993718/)

Answer (score 4):

На этот вопрос нет однозначного и простого ответа. Есть несколько способов, как этот вопрос решать и в каждом конкретном случае нужно взвешивать за и против для этого конкретного случая.

### Статический метод

Этот способ самый простой в реализации и это его плюс. Минус такой, что клиенты класса `Utils` жестко привязаны к `calculation` и заменить его на другой нельзя просто.

### Создание объекта при использовании

```
class A {
  void f() {
     Utils utils = new Utils();

     utils.calcuation();
  }

}
```

Из плюсов - довольно просто. Иногда полезно, что экземпляры изолированны, например, если нужно добавить кеширование на время выполнения конеретного метода.

Из минусов - жесткая привязка клиента к реализации, невозможно подменить ее. Если методы вызываются часто и создание делается часто, то возможны проблемы с производительностью.

### Создание объекта один раз

```
class A {
  Utils utils = new Utils();


  void f() {
     util.calculation();
  }
  
}
```

Минусы и плюсы похожи на предыдущий случай, только все происходит на уровне класса, а не метода.

### Паттерн Одиночка он же Синглтон

Это способ отвязать клиентов от конкретного экземпляра. В этом случае можно делать замену используемого объекта, например для тестирования, если сделать возможность замены объекта.

### Внедрение зависимости a.k.a. Dependency Injection

```
class A {
  Utils utils;
  public A(Utils utils) {
     this.utils = utils;
  }
  void f() {
    utils.calculation(..);
  }
}
```

В этом способе класс A не знает ничего о том, откуда берется объект, который он использует. Это обязанность внешнего кода сконфигурировать зависимости для A. В больших программах для этого используют фреймворки типа guice или spring.

Плюс - минимум зависимостей и максимум возможности конфигурировать. Минус - доп. код, который будет делать конфигурацию.

### Паттерн Service Locator

Это более обобщенный singleton. В этом случае клиент зависит от класса, который дает доступ собственно к зависимости:

```
class ServiceLocator {

   public Util getUtil() {
      ...
   }
}

class A {
   private ServiceLocator locator;

   public A(ServiceLocator locator) {
      this.locator = locator;
   }

   public void f() {
      locator.getUtils().calculation(..);
   }
}
```

Эта зависимость на сам `ServiceLocator` может быть тоже выражена по разному (все способы, которые описаны выше применимы - тут я использовал внедрение зависимости).