# Как мокнуть (Mock) Extention method?

Tags: c#, mock

Код:

```
public class SomeStaticClass //содержится в отдельном nu-get пакете
{
    public ResponseObject SomeStaticMethod(string input) //замокать метод
    {
        return SomeStaticClass.SomeStaticMethod(input);
    }
}
```

Он используется в юнит тестах ( используется framework Mock) и **SomeStaticMethod необходимо замокать.**

Я вычитал что можно сделать **wrapper** для SomeStaticClass, но мне кажется, мне это твариант не подходит, т.к. тогда (как я понимаю) я должен по всему проекту заменить SomeStaticClass  на свой враппер, если я правильно его понимаю.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно замокать SomeStaticMethod ?

Спасибо

**UPD
SomeStaticClass нельзя изменять, т.к. он находится в отдельном пакете**

Comment: Приведите _реальный_ код. Сейчас вы вызываете метод `SomeStaticMethod` из самого себя, что приводит к переполнению стэка.

Comment: 1. Приведите реальный код, это ни разу не extension method (нет this) и даже не статический метод (нет static) 2. для ext method читать тут: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2295960/5752652

Comment: Если вы задумываетесь над тем, чтобы замокать extension-методы, либо любые другие статические методы, то вам стоит обернуть эти методы в интерфейс и мокать именно интерфейс

Comment: дубль? [Мокинг статических методов. Когда это нужно делать?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/814207/179763)

Comment: По идее все верно понимаете - пишете свой враппер (может даже и с интерфейсом) и везде все использования статического метода меняете на свой враппер.

Comment: Не закрывайте вопрос, пожалуйста. Я дам подробный ответ (нужно время), как всё-таки замокать это дело.

Answer (score 9):

Лучше всего, конечно, избавиться от статических методов и классов. Выделить интерфейс и сделать класс, имплементирующий его. Тогда этот интерфейс можно элементарно мокать.

Вы пишете, что не можете переписать код статического класса. Тогда, как вы сами написали, нужно сделать оболочку-wrapper. При этом придётся менять код везде, где вызывается этот класс.

---

Изолирующие фреймворки (Isolation Frameworks) есть двух видов: ограниченные (constrained) и неограниченные (unconstrained).

Moq, наряду с NSubstitute и FakeItEasy относится к ограниченным. Они позволяют замокать только виртуальные члены.

К неограниченным относятся TypeMock Isolator, JustMock (оба платные) и Microsoft Fakes (входит в состав Visual Studio Enterprise, отсутствует в версиях Community и даже Professional).

Последние позволяют замокать что угодно: скрытые и внутренние, статические и запечатанные типы и члены. В какой-то мере это облегчает тестирование, но развращает и в итоге можно скатиться к плохой архитектуре без чёткого разделения на области видимости и т. п.

Мне доводилось использовать TypeMock. Если кратко - вещь! Мокает абсолютно всё! Если вам позволяют финансы, рекомендую.

MS Fakes тоже сильная вещь. Но сделано в духе Майкрософт: всё или ничего. Автоматически генерирует тонны кода. Вроде и удобно, но пойди разберись...

---

Не так давно я наткнулся на интересную библиотеку [Pose](https://github.com/tonerdo/pose), которая тоже позволяет замокать многое. Но она всё же сильно уступает коммерческим аналогам и написание шимов с её помощью та ещё задача.

Покажу пример её использования. Так как вы не привели реальный код, я накидаю примерный.

Класс со статическим методом, который нужно замокать:

```
public class SomeStaticClass
{
    public static ResponseObject SomeStaticMethod(string input)
    {
        return new ResponseObject { Value = input.ToUpper() };
    }
}
```

```
public class ResponseObject
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Класс, в котором используется статический:

```
public class Foo
{
    public ResponseObject Bar(string input)
    {
        return SomeStaticClass.SomeStaticMethod(input);
    }
}
```

Используется примерно так:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var response = foo.Bar("abc");
Console.WriteLine(response.Value); // ABC
```

Пишем тест.

Устанавливаем [пакет](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pose).
Открываем пространство имён:

```
using Pose;
```

Тест без мока:

```
var foo = new Foo();

var actual = foo.Bar("abc").Value;

Assert.AreEqual("ABC", actual);
```

Тест с использованием шима:

```
var foo = new Foo();

Shim some = Shim
    .Replace(() => SomeStaticClass.SomeStaticMethod(Is.A<string>()))
    .With((string _) => new ResponseObject { Value = "fake" });

string actual = null;

PoseContext.Isolate(() =>
{
    actual = foo.Bar("abc").Value;
},
some);

Assert.AreEqual("fake", actual);
```

Тут указано, что нужно заменить (Replace) вызов нашего статического метода другим результатом (With).

---

Возможности Pose невелики. Поэтому, после знакомства с ней, я стал искать аналоги.

Нашёл некую библиотеку [Harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony). Судя по описанию и примерам, с её помощью можно добиться нужного результата. Но использование выглядит сложно.

Другая библиотека: [MethodRedirect](https://github.com/spinico/MethodRedirect). Судя по имеющимся примерам кода, тоже может подменять статические (и другие) методы.

[Prig](https://urasandesu.github.io/Prig/) - опен-сорсная альтернатива Microsoft Fakes. Если имеете представление о MS Fakes, можете попробовать.

Ну и напоследок не могу не упомянуть великий и могучий Fody, а именно: [Ionad.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Ionad). Подменяет код на этапе компиляции (вернее, после неё).

Разработка многих упомянутых библиотек прекращена или почти не ведётся.

[AutoFake](https://github.com/Serg046/AutoFake) - этот проект продолжает развиваться.

[Shimmy](https://github.com/frogsquire/shimmy) - ещё один проект, основанный на Pose.

---

Резюме.

Способов решения вашей задачи много. Самый лучший описан в начале.
Если остановите свой выбор на какой-то библиотеке, не спрашивайте решение в комментариях, создавайте отдельную тему с вопросом.

Comment: На самом деле у harnomy довольно простое использование. `Memory.DetourMethod(source, dest)` - в итоге при вызове source на самом деле будет вызван dest