# Возможно ли выполнять часть кода метода только при исполнении в тесте?

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Собственно, вопрос в том, можно ли реализовать это без использования дополнительных параметров. Если конкретно, в этом коде:

```
public static bool CheckAndStep(
    ref int x,
    ref int y,
    Direction direction,
    ref VirtualPoint[,] map,
    Point start,
    bool isBack
)
{
    if (
        map[
            x + direction.X,
            y + direction.Y
        ].Flag < 3
        || (
            isBack
            && map[
                x + direction.X,
                y + direction.Y
            ].Flag != 3
        )
    )
    {
        if (start.X != x || start.Y != y)
        {
            if (map[x + direction.X, y + direction.Y].Flag == 4) map[x, y].Flag = 3;
            map[x + direction.X, y + direction.Y].Flag = 4;
        }
        if (!isBack) Logger.Write(
            x
            + ", "
            + y
            + " -> "
            + (x + direction.X)
            + ", "
            + (y + direction.Y)
        );
        else Logger.Write(
            + (x + direction.X)
            + ", "
            + (y + direction.Y)
            + " <- "
            + x
            + ", "
            + y
        );
        x += direction.X;
        y += direction.Y;
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Мне нужно, чтобы `Logger.Write()` срабатывал только в тесте, но не при обычном выполнении программы.

Comment: Подсказка: у вас слишком много конкатенаций, это очень медленно работает, попробуйте переписать на `StringBuilder`.

Comment: `Мне нужно, чтобы Logger.Write() срабатывал только в тесте` Обычно так не делают, а делают так: объявляют в конструкторе зависимость от ILogger, а в тестах подкладывают нужную реализацию. А в продакшене конфигурируют логгер в зависимости от конфиг-файла, например проставляют уровень логирования в verbose/silent и путь в нужное место в %program data%. А так как вы хотите сделать... это придётся класс логгера делать знающим либо специальный параметр, либо знание об окружении (допустим, environment machinename, путей или чего-то ещё). Это хрупко, ломко -- лучше так не делать.

Comment: Плюс [можно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13532856/5752652) писать в консоль теста через Trace.WriteLine

Comment: Как правильно сделать, вам написал A K. / Учитывая, что Logger с большой буквы, это класс со статическим методом? [Здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217) я расписал, как это можно замокать.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под _тестом_? Модульный тест? И зачем вам в нём что-то куда-то выводить? Там должны быть ассёрты и всё.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov модульный тест, да. Просто мне нужно понимать, почему он не срабатывает, а для этого я вывожу в лог последовательность действий. Конечно, можно потом просто закомментировать или убрать запись в лог, но мне кажется, что это будет не слишком профессионально.

Comment: Почему не срабатывает - это выясняется на этапе [отладки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/?view=vs-2019). А тест просто сигнализирует: выполняется код правильно или нет. Если правильно - хорошо. Если неправильно - снова выполняете отладку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, со статическим методом всё верно, там даже явного конструктора нет, он просто хранит методы для записи логов.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я отладку и запускаю, но для теста, в самой программе этот метод нигде ещё не используется.

Comment: @aepot а `String.Format()` не подойдёт?

Comment: @aepot просто для `StringBuilder` надо заранее знать максимальную длину строки, как я понял, а я её не знаю.

Comment: @aepot, `string.Format` внутри себя использует StringBuilder

Comment: не надо, просто `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder()` и вперёд.

Comment: @Grundy ок, сливаюсь. :) спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, вам не должно такого хотеться.

Смысл юнит-теста как раз в том и состоит, что он тестирует ваш метод *как он есть*. Если вы тестируете одно, а в production исполняется другое, зачем тогда был весь тест?

Если вам нужна *отладка*, то можете добавить любой отладочный код, но обязательно уберите его после того, как ошибка будет найдена. Отладочному коду не место в вашем методе, когда отладка завершится.

Если вам нужно *логирование* (не только для отладки), тогда имеет смысл абстрагироваться от конкретного логгера, и логировать через интерфейс наподобие `ILogger` (а уж за поставку конкретной реализации может отвечать, например, dependency injection).

Comment: еще `#if DEBUG` можно.

Comment: @aepot: Мммм, я как-то сомневаюсь, зачем вообще хранить отладочный код после того, как проблема будет решена? Его ещё и поддерживать придётся. А пока идёт отладка, `#if DEBUG` тоже ни к чему.

Comment: например, если логирование нужно, если это отладочный билд, а не релизный.

Comment: @aepot: Если это не отладочный код, а код логирования, то тогда DI нам в помощь, просто заинжектируем пустой логгер в релизном режиме. Иначе у нас есть риск, что в DEBUG и RELEASE-билдах будет выполняться разный код (например, код логирования может ненамеренно создавать побочные эффекты).

Comment: верно, в зависимости от потребностей, можно по-всякому это вертеть, я просто написал типа "а еще вот такое есть".

Comment: @aepot: В такой формулировке не могу не согласиться.

Comment: Добавлю, что если хочется тестировать часть метода (ну вот хочется), это говорит о том, что метод нужно аккуратно разбить на несколько методов поменьше и проблема уйдет.