# Замокать(Moq) вспомогательный метод в классе

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, moq, mstest

Есть класс(и его интерфейс) у него есть два метода А и B. Метод B выполняет вспомогательную функцию т.е он вызывается только из метода А. Нужно создать Moq объект что бы вспомогательный метод всегда возвращал только true.

Делаю так:

```
var mock = new Mock<IA>();
mock.Setup(w => w.Ab(It.IsAny<short>()))
    .Returns(true);
```

, но он сейчас выполняет свою функцию т.е обрабатывает данные не хочет возвращать всегда true. Возможно ли создать moq метода и вызвать его из этого же класса?

Comment: Вы не добавили код интерфеса, но похоже что B не является частью интерфейса. https://stackoverflow.com/q/20400734/5752652 Либо - делайте виртуальным и не приватным хотя бы.

Comment: Метода B в интерфейсе нет. Другие объекты не должны обращаться к этому методу

Comment: Выносите метод B в отдельный класс как зависимость, в тесте подсовывайте вместо него мок

Comment: Можно вынести зависимость от этого метода в интерфейс и передавать аргументом основного метода. Мне казалось что можно создать через Moq и подменить этот метод. Как бы тесты недолжны влиять на основной код

Comment: Ну, по-грамотному да, не должны, но иногда знание о тестах всё же просачивается в виде internal (InternalsVisibleTo в csproj), virtual и т.п. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Так-то вы если хотите - можете оставить B приватным и честно тестировать только публичный метод А - просто тестов придётся больше писать. Либо давайте честно декомпозировать согласно SPR и объявлять зависимости. Но либо - либо, не стоит пытаться усидеть на двух стульях и при этом сетовать на кривизну фреймворков тестирования.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217 - тут я перечислил некоторые средства, с помощью которых можно замокать (вернее, зафейкать) невиртуальные методы.