# Как в тестировании задавать время?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, тестирование

Делаю тесты на запросы, внутри контроллера считывается время: `DateTime.Now`.

Как задавать время у этого элемента или как-то время можно задавать во время создания `WebHostBuilder`.

```
public TestWebEnvironment()
{
    var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseEnvironment("Test")
        .UseStartup<Startup>();

    Server = new TestServer(builder);
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
}

private RequestBuilder BuildRequest(string url)
{
    var uri = new Uri(Server.BaseAddress, url);
    var builder = Server.CreateRequest(url);

    var cookieHeader = CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader(uri);
    builder.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookieHeader))
    {
        builder.AddHeader(HeaderNames.Cookie, cookieHeader);           
    }

    return builder;
}
```

Вызываю контроллеры:

```
var response = await BuildRequest(url).GetAsync()
```

Не очень понимаю, как тут можно задать текущее время?
asp.core 3.1

Comment: Вероятно, самый распространённый способ, сделать интерфейс `IDateTime` и инжектить его реализации. [Пример](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Напрямую - никак. Вынесите получение времени в отдельный интерфейс: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#stub-static-references

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217 - здесь я перечислил несколько разных способов замокать почти что угодно.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас посмотрю