# AccessViolationException при попытке задать значение поинтеру

Tags: c#, сборщик-мусора, unsafe

Пытаюсь изменить значения в таблице методов в рантайме для GC, это относительно успешно получается для некоторых методов, но для некоторых я получаю AccessViolationException. Почему?

В конкретном коде ниже я получаю исключение при попытке изменить поинтер на метод для `GC` `Int32 _CollectionCount(Int32, Int32)`. В чем ошибка? Почему я вылезаю за границы доступной мне памяти? У меня есть теория: после того, как я сделал методы jited (методом RuntimeHelpers), то в таблицу добавляется новое значение тем самым сдвигая другие. Но это глупо, как мне кажется

```
class Program
{
    private unsafe static void Main()
    {
        var srcMethods = typeof(GC).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).Where(x => x.Name.Contains("col", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        var dest = typeof(Program).GetMethod("ToMethod");


        JumpTo(srcMethods.First(), dest);
        GC.Collect(0);
    }
    public void ToMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("to method");
    }

    public unsafe static void JumpTo(MethodBase from, MethodBase to)
    {
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(from.MethodHandle);
        RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(to.MethodHandle);

        var fromFp = from.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();
        var toFp = to.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer();

        var fromPtr = (byte*)fromFp.ToPointer();
        var toPtr = (byte*)toFp.ToPointer();

        var jump = (uint)fromPtr + 1 + 4;

        *(uint*)(fromPtr + 1) = (uint)(toPtr - jump);
    }
}
```

Comment: В какой строке исключение, и что вообще из этого должно получиться? А вообще исполняемая память недоступна для записи. Попробуйте прочитать этот же адрес, если прочитается, то я прав.

Comment: @aepot в последней строке метода `JumpTo`. "Что должно получиться" - при вызове метода `from` будет вызван на самом деле метод `to`. На данный момент я стремлюсь к тому, чтобы GC не работал, но у меня не получается в силу скудных знаний о рантайме .NET.

Comment: Насколько мне известно, заморозить сборку мусора невозможно. Единственный способ это сделать, известный мне, это скачать исходники .NET с гитхаба, исправить то что нужно в коде самого GC и собрать свой собственный .NET

Comment: Хочется изменить поведение чужого кода вообще во всей системе? Или только в своём приложении?

Comment: [Harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony), [MethodRedirect](https://github.com/spinico/MethodRedirect). Не? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217 - тут ещё библиотеки перечислены

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, знаком с данными либами, но мне пока не хочется использовать их, потому что подобные вопросы для меня скорее полезное развлечение, а вызвав метод библиотеки - ничего не пойму кто там и куда заменилось. К слову harmony как раз делает то, что и я, только там навороченнее и поддержка mono

Comment: Понятно, принято.