# Получить количество запросов за конкретный период которые были направлены для конкретной таблицы в MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть реализация кэша на языке C# с использованием паттерна блокировка с двойной проверкой, который по своей сути блокирует потоки и запрашивает у сервера только часть которую хочет получить или другую часть которая не была запрошена ранее.

Мне нужно посчитать количество запросов к конкретной таблице в БД, своего рода счетчик, без изменения самого кода (NUnit тест). Можно ли получать количество запросов к конкретной таблице через Entity Framework? или SQL запрос? Получить количество выполненных запросов, через Базу данных, без счетчика в коде!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Непонятно, где вы хотите считать это количество запросов. Если в своём коде, то введите переменную-счётчик и меняйте его потокобезопасно (например, с помощью Interlocked.Increment). А можно узнавать эту информацию в самой СУБД. [sys.dm_os_performance_counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16), https://stackoverflow.com/a/9842400/5045688

Comment: Чисто теоретически Я знаю количество раз сколько будет запросов в БД, пишу тест, сам код не могу изменять, Я буду ожидать например 3 раза был запрос и в проверке стоит 3, а получить реальный ответ от БД как? что именно 3 раза у нее из этой таблицы запросили данные? не больше не меньше

Comment: Я понимаю может как то отслеживать транзакции и уже там отбирать к какой таблице был запрос

Comment: Примерно понятно, что нужно. Но немножко кода не помешает, чтобы прояснить. / [Testing EF Core Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/). Вероятно, нужно создавать для тестов новую БД и потом из неё получать количество запросов. / Или же проблема в том, что не используется инъкция зависимостей и поэтому не получается замокать невиртуальные члены? Тут либо код переписать кардинально, либо использовать unconstrained мокающие фреймворки - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217