# Изменение функциональности для возможности протестировать

Tags: c#

Подскажите по организации сервиса, микросервиса или как это называется и его модульному тестированию.

У меня есть класс `MyService`

У него есть некоторые зависимости, `HttpClient`,`ILogService`,`MyServiceData`

Есть только 2 публичных метода, `Start` и `Stop`

Он в цикле выполняет `get` запрос,десириализует ответ и размещает его в `MyServiceData`

Я как разрабочик, вроде как должен протестировать его поведение не обращая внимание на его детали реализации.

Но ухватиться не за что, так как из публичного только `Start` и `Stop` ничего не возвращающие и не принимающие)

Как такое изменить, чтобы хотя бы запрос / ответ тестировать) ?

Поселить какого то `get` реквестера как зависимость чтобы тестировать его хотя бы можно было ?

Или есть какой то лучше подход ?

**UPD - Инжектится**

```
    static void Main()
    {
        IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<ILogService, DefaultLogService>()
            .AddSingleton<HttpClient>()
            .AddSingleton<MyServiceData>()
            .AddSingleton<MyService>();

        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

        MyService? mService = serviceProvider.GetService<MyService>();
        checkerIATAService?.Start();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Мокать зависимости, вызвать старт/стоп, проверить, что нужные зависимости были вызваны. Хз какие сейчас есть инструменты для мокинга, в крайнем случае можно сделать интерфейсы для хтттп клиента и для myservicedata и вместо боевых объектов подставлять свои реализации. Ключевые слова для таких вещей: mock, stub, fake

Comment: Есть книжка - Art of unit testing от автора роя ашерова, там как раз про дотнет и про тестирование - почитайте, будет полезно

Comment: на русском http://d.mitridat.in.ua/oserouv_r_iskusstvo_avtonomnogo.pdf

Comment: @tym32167 да, у меня понимание есть о `mock`, `stub`, `fake`, я реальные зависимости могу использовать, с этим проблем нет. Проблема с тем, что в данный момент у меня есть варианты только реализацию тестировать. А в книжках говорится про то что надо `public` только тестировать и не раскрывать для тестов `private`, а публичное тут только `Start` и `Stop` ничего не возвращающие. Получается у меня какой то кривой класс который нужно разделить на больше абстракций, которые уже можно будет протестировать.

Comment: Во первых, если у вас Юнит тестирование, то только моки/стабы/фейки, никаких реализаций зависимостей участвовать не должно в тесте. Во вторых, вы текструете у функции вход, выход и побочные эффекты. Вход - это парамеры функции, выход - это возвращаемое значение, побочные эффекты - это как раз что функция должна что то скачать и потом куда то сохранить.

Comment: Зависимости должны инжектироваться (Dependency Injection), только в этом случае их можно замокать. Если этого нет, то код следует переписать полностью. / Можно попробовать использовать unconstrained (неограниченные) мок-фреймворки, но это малораспространено и не рекомендуется. Здесь я их перечислил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да - инжектится