# Аналог JNI только в C#

Tags: c++, windows

Существует ли какой-нибудь аналог JNI только для работы с приложениями на C#/VB? Если да, то посоветуйте.

Comment: Да. В .NET эта штука называется P/Invoke. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke

Comment: Нет. Мне нужно искать классы, менять поля программы на сишарпе прямо из своей динамической библиотеки на C++, мне не нужно вызывать методы из библиотек в самом сишарпе.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217 - тут я перечислил библиотеки, которые позволяют подменять (мокать) члены типов .NET. Но надо использовать C#, а не C++. Возможно, сгодится C++/CLI.

Comment: Есть ещё известная библиотека [dnlib](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib), которую применяют для изменения сборок.