Как снизить зависимость нескольких классов друг от друга при применении композиции?
Делаю небольшую программку, которая должна открывать файлы .cs, созданные в Visual Studio. Для того, чтобы открывались именно нужные файлы, нужно анализировать файлы решения и всех проектов из него (.sln и .csproj). Для представления в программе написал простенькую структуру из трех классов, которыми предполагалось представлять в программе каждое отдельное решение. Классы объединены по принципу композиции, за создание каждого отдельного класса предполагалось сделать ответственным статический метод внутри этого класса. На данный момент все выглядит примерно так:
public class Solution
{
    public List<Project> Projects { get; }

    private Solution(params Project[] projects)
    {
        Projects = projects.ToList();
    }

    public static Solution CreateFromFile(string pathToFile)
    {
        return new Solution(
            pathToFile, 
            ProjectFileHelper.ExtractFilePaths(
                File.ReadAllText(pathToFile), 
                FileExtension.Sln)
                    .Select(path => Project.CreateFromFile(path))
                    .ToArray());
    }
}

Класс Project и CodeFile выглядят аналогично, за исключением логики метода CreateFromFile класса CodeFile - он просто открывает кодовый файл как текст и записывает в поле.
Выглядит вроде бы чистенько - инкапсуляция, композиция, все дела... Однако данная галиматья совершенно нетестируема по причине того, что объекты Project и CodeFile создаются самим классом Solution, а не получаются им извне. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как следовало рассуждать с самого начала, решая задачу представления проекта студии в своей программе? Сложность-то у нее смешная...

Пусть уж лучше будет 2 разных класса, чем сидеть искать откуда растут ноги у каждого разного класса. Или воспользуйтесь готовым от Майкрософт https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/blob/37eb419ad2c986ac5530292e6ee08e962390249e/src%2FBuild%2FConstruction%2FSolution%2FSolutionFile.cs

Спасибо за ответ! Только я не понял, что вы имели ввиду на счет двух разных классов и их ног...) Можно чуть подробнее?

Этот код тоже можно тестировать с помощью неограниченных (unconstrained) мокающих фреймворков: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222511/184217. Но да, такой подход не рекомендуется.

Как сделать по уму. Делаете интерфейсы. Конструктор Solution принимает их. Создаёте классы, реализующие эти интерфейсы. Инжектируете их в конструктор Solution. Вместо вызовов статических методов будут вызовы методов интерфейсов. Теперь код тестируется обычными способами.

Спасибо за ответ! Интерфейс лучше один все три класса, или каждому свой? От статического метода для создания объекта лучше отказаться? У меня получилось то, что получилось потому, что я хотел разместить всю логику создания объектов внутри них самих - статические методы принимали бы только путь к файлу на диске, а конструктору бы передавали готовую коллекцию объектов. Сложность в том, что Solution создает объекты Project, а они (сами) создают свои объекты CodeFile. Как ни крути, а без четвертого объекта, который будет знать о них обо всех тут не обойтись...
