# C# Windows Forms Глобальный объект

Tags: c#, winforms

Использую SQLite в своем приложении и не хочу закрывать, открывать соединение или передавать всем конструкторам форм его. Как открыть его один раз и брать откуда угодно?

Comment: `Как открыть его один раз и брать откуда угодно?` Хотите выстрелить себе в ногу? Зачем вам такое вообще понадобилось?

Comment: А вообще вам нужен [синглтон](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768396/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0/768523#768523), но прежде чем делать то. что вы хотите, подумайте ещё раз - надо ли оно вам, так как вы хотите делать неправильную вещь

Comment: Читайте про [connection pool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling)

Comment: @tym32167 Зачем же Синглтон, когда есть Dependency Injection(DI)?

Comment: Это тоже самое что открывать потоки и не разрушать их ... У вас должно быть открыто соединение только когда идёт обработка данных с бд, а иначе делать не целесообразно, как вам ваше уже и написали

Comment: Виноват, похоже, в sqlite пулинг по умолчанию выключен (включить: [Pooling=True](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/)). Но тем не менее, с понятием пула соединений ознакомиться надо.

Comment: Да я понимаю и открываю и закрываю соединения. Вопрос в том, что если соединения устанавливают клиенты асинхронно? Получается пока один открыл соединение второй пытается открыть еще одно. SQLite выдает Exception

Comment: Если вам надо синхронизировать доступ ресурсу, то используйте конструкции синхронизации (мониторы, например). А создание только 1 контекста проблему не решит, так как параллельные запросы никуда не денутся

Comment: @tym32167 Немного подчистил свои комменты. Тот ответ тоже излишне перегружен, что я не думаю имеет место возможность продолжение обсуждения. Хочется добавить с моей точки зрения советовать свою реализацию паттерна синглтон с DI  было избыточно для данного вопроса. Можно было посоветовать чего полегче, тот же uow к примеру. Если обратиться к вики, то ваш паттерн и есть DI, без всяких синглтонов, где IAmSingletone является сервисом.

Comment: @Anamnian ну это не моя реализация, я просто зарегал класс в контейнере как синглтон - не более того, и ссылка просто указывает на пример как это делать. (комменты почистил тоже)

Comment: @Anamnian что касается того, как это называть - то тот пример четко следует определению синглтона, потому называется синглтоном. То, что реализация не кажется знакомой не делает его менее одиночкой :)