# Generic поле c доступом new(), и закрытый конструктор

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Имеется класс примерно представляющий абстрактный класс, класса одиночки:

```
/// <summary>
///     Представляет базовую реализацию абстрактного класса одиночки.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Тип объекта одиночки.</typeparam>
public abstract class SingleInstance<T> where T : class, new()
{
    private static T instance_;
    private static object syncRoot_ = new object();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Возвращает ссылку на объект одиночку.
    /// </summary>
    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot_)
            {
                return instance_ ?? (instance_ = new T());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Кхм, а теперь к делу, у класса одиночки должен быть закрытый конструктор, при этом `Generic` тип, не допускает использование опреатора `new` для закрытого конструктора.

Как быть в таких ситуациях? Неужели для каждого класса одиночки придется делать копипаст?

Comment: Современный подход – не создавать синглтоны явно, а отдавать создание и поддержание единственности экземпляра класса на откуп DI-контейнеру

Comment: вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768396/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0/768523#768523) есть интересный тред и ответы на подумать - полностью согласен с Андреем

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Смотрите, вашему базовому классу нужно как-то создать экземпляр. Метод с открытым конструктором, разумеется, не подходит, т. к. у вас при этом нарушается основное свойство синглтона — гарантия существования единственного экземпляра.

Каким же способом можно создать экземпляр, если конструктор приватный? Например, при помощи рефлексии:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private static T instance_;
    private static object syncRoot_ = new object();

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot_)
            {
                return instance_ ?? (instance_ = Create());
            }
        }
    }

    static private T Create() => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), nonPublic: true);
}
```

Этот код, разумеется, упадёт, если у вашего `T` нету конструктора без аргументов. Впрочем, для синглтона аргументы конструктора обычно не имеют смысла.

Данный метод, кстати, довольно медленный, т. к. `Activator.CreateInstance` — не самая быстрая функция. Впрочем, `new T()` на текущий момент под капотом [также пользуется `Activator.CreateInstance`](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgBgATIIwG4CwAUMgMyYBM6AwgDwAqAfOgO4AWApgE5vq0joB2bJgAoAlIQDehdDMylkAFnQBZMdNlSCs7QKE8x+LbIC+hY0A==), так что это не медленнее вашей текущей версии.

Другой метод, который мне приходит в голову — затребовать порождённый класс предоставить функцию для создания экземпляра самостоятельно. Но абстрактных статических функций в C# нет, а выставлять поле-делегат и ожидать от производного класса, что он его заполнит, не очень хорошо, т. к. подсказки от компилятора при нарушении не будет.

На всякий случай, вот код.

```
// не рекомендуется!
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    private static T instance_;
    private static object syncRoot_ = new object();
    protected static Func<T> Create;

    public static T Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot_)
            {
                return instance_ ?? (instance_ = Create());
            }
        }
    }

    static Singleton()
    {
        // нужно, чтобы статический конструктор T отработал
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(
            typeof(T).TypeHandle);
    }
}

class X : Singleton<X>
{
    private X() { }
    static X() { Create = () => new X(); }
}
```

---

Заметьте, что [канонический метод создания синглтонов](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx#lazy) гораздо более лаконичен:

```
class X
{
    private static readonly Lazy<X> lazy = new Lazy<X>(() => new X());
    public static X Instance => lazy.Value;
    private X() { }
}
```

Если вы захотите вынести этот код в абстрактный суперкласс, вы столкнётесь с теми же проблемами: код должен как-то создать экземпляр «чужого» класса с приватным конструктором. Например, решение с рефлексией будет выглядеть так:

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> where T : class
{
    protected static readonly Lazy<T> lazy =
        new Lazy<T>(() => (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), nonPublic: true));
    public static T Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }
}
```

Comment: `Lazy` потокобезопасен?

Comment: @LLENN: Согласно документации, да, если не указывать специального флага в конструкторе.

Comment: *режим зануды* - наверное стоит дополнить, что в классической блокировке с двойной проверкой проверки таки две, чтобы лишний раз не блочить поток (говорю про первые 2 примера - проверка на null до лока и после)

Comment: @tym32167: Я, честно говоря, так и не нашёл в спецификации языка, почему первый доступ (без блокировки) к разделяемой переменной вообще законен, поэтому я бы про него лучше умолчал :)