# Корректно ли называть static классы, как типы реализующие паттерн Singleton?

Tags: c#, терминология

Начал листать книжку **C# 7 и .NET Core. Кросс-платформенная разработка для профессионалов. 3-е издание** и наткнулся на такую фразу:

> Паттерн Singleton. Это один из самых распространенных паттернов
>   проектирования. Его примерами в .NET служат типы Console и Math.

Да, статика схожа по смыслу с Singleton, но разве верно называть любую статику Singleton'ом?

P.S По моему книга мусор. Поправьте меня, если кто знаком с ней и я что-то упускаю. Как бы первые 150 стр описывается какой-то базис => не понятно почему плашка "для профессионолов". Я ожидал, что там будут затронуты вопросы переносимости, но я их в упор не вижу...

Comment: статика лишь один из возможных вариантов реализации шаблона «одиночка»

Comment: @StrangerintheQ так-то да. Но, как я понимаю, автор уверяет что статиска и одиночка- это синонимы. Если с консолью я кое-как могу согласится, то со статическим Math у меня большие сомнения.

Comment: [Difference between static class and singleton pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/519530/2881286)

Comment: Синглтон - это тип, от которого доступен только один экземпляр.  Можем ли мы считать, что `Math` - это экзепляр типа?

Comment: @tym32167 а сам по себе статический класс не является экземпляром самого себя? Статический класс помечен, как запечатанный. Есть конструктор, который вызывается только единожды при обращении к классу. Присутствует глобальная точка доступа. При этом данные полей этого класса помещаются в кучу и у каждого процесса он свой. Да и синглтон - это не тип, а шаблон, и шаблону вроде как соответствует. Так что формально - это синглтон, но не тот синглтон, который обычно требуется при упоминании этого слова)

Comment: Возможно, здесь имеет место быть ошибка перевода. Хотя вряд ли так значительно могли исказить смысл при переводе, но все же как вариант.

Comment: При желании, можно написать автору книги/раздела_книги на почту и уточнить этот момент.

Comment: @John ты не можешь с ним оперировать как с объектом, например передать в качестве параметра методу

Comment: @John на ваше определение синглтона можно что угодно натянуть. Например, типы тоже хранятся в куче и к типу тоже есть единая точка доступа. Значит ли что любой тип (например, `int`) - синглтон? Строка "вася" тоже может быть одна на процесс, если вы не создали вторую такую же в обход интернирования. Значит ли это, что строка "вася" - синглтон? Статические поля, отмеченные аттрибутом `ThreadStatic` будут существовать отдельным экземпляром для каждого потока. Значит ли это, что статические поля с этим аттрибутом - не синглтон? Тип внутри DI контейнера (синглтон-регистрация)-является ли сингтоном?

Comment: @tym32167 это не моё определение - википедии. Я лишь говорю, что формально - это синглтон, на практике же конечно нет. Что касается ваших примеров: 1) Типы по определению являются **разными** экземплярами одного класса `Type`, что противоречит шаблону (только один экземпляр). 2) В процессе работы программы можно создать ещё один экземпляр строки "вася"? Это тоже противоречит шаблону - один экземпляр. 3) ThreadStatic идёт вразрез с шаблоном - согласен. Но тоже самое и с обычным синглтоном будет, если у instance поставите этот атрибут.

Comment: @tym32167 впрочем с оперированием, как с экземпляром - это да, промах. Экземпляра всё-таки не создаётся. Никогда не интересовался, но посмотрел IL: по факту static класса как такового нет - это обычный abstract sealed класс, и никакого экземпляра этого класса не создаётся.

Comment: @John это именно ваша трактовка термина "экземпляр класса", ведь если взять определение сингтона, то `порождающий шаблон проектирования, гарантирующий, что в однопроцессном приложении будет единственный экземпляр некоторого класса, и предоставляющий глобальную точку доступа к этому экземпляру`, а вот что говорит нам дока: [a static class cannot be instantiated](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members), то есть нет в природе экземпляра статического класса, а значит, формально он не синглтон.

Comment: @John ну вот, пока писал вам ответ, вы сами себе ответили :)

Comment: @tym32167 просто до сути люблю докапываться) Одно дело читать доку, где тупо написано, что "не создаётся". А другое дело разобраться, а что там вообще творится-то в закулисье. В общем, резюмируя: статический класс в .NET - не синглтон.

Comment: @John ну я, например, предаочитаю думать не о конкретной реализации, а о приципе. То есть да, для меня статический класс не сингтон, но вот в DI контейнере вполне себе синлгтон. Я уже как то [общался](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/768523/179763) на эту тему.